# How do you do fulltext search add two field with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, mysql, ef-core-5.0

If only one field is searched, it can be successful.
But not two.

```
var results = db.tables
    .Where(x => EF.Functions.Match(x.Title, "search text",MySqlMatchSearchMode.Boolean));
```

I want to get sql syntax result.

```
select * from articles 
where match(`title`) against('葡萄牙') > 0;
```

Below is the result I want to achieve.

```
var results = db.tables
    .Where(x => EF.Functions.Match(x.Title+x.ArticleContent, "search text"));
```

I want to get sql syntax result.

```
select * from articles 
where match(`title`,`article_content`) against('葡萄牙') > 0;
```

Error :
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(`s`.`title`, COALESCE(`s`.`article_content`, ''))) AGAINST ('葡萄牙' IN BOOL...' at line 3

Comment: Use an OR operation `||`? Concatting the fields together could cause an error anyway: two fields of "my name is bob" and "cats are my favorite" dont actually contain the word "bobcats" anywhere.. until you CON(bob)CAT them together 

Answer (score 1):

Because I found the answer, share the answer
URL : <https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/blob/f4b1ab9497743db5a395a36340515b3d3fc28e3c/test/EFCore.MySql.FunctionalTests/Query/MatchQueryMySqlTest.cs >

```
var results = db.tables
    .Where(x => EF.Functions.Match(new [] {x.Title,x.ArticleContent}, "search text"));
```

Comment: I'd like to add that for the moment is doesn't work in MySQL.EntityFrameworkCore (provided by Oracle, I assume), it works only on Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.

Comment: But works almost perfectly, supports ordering and allows to use .Include() without changing the order. 

That is why I had to switch the whole project to Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.